# How to print same dictionary object from multiple urls with grequest?

Tags: python, json, api, grequests

I have a list of URLs that all use the same json structure. I am trying to pull specific dictionary objects from all of the URLs at once with grequest. I am able to do it with one URL, though I am using request:

```
import requests
import json

main_api = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-1ST&type=both&depth=50'

json_data = requests.get(main_api).json()    

Quantity = json_data['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity']
Rate = json_data['result']['buy'][0]['Rate']
Quantity_2 = json_data['result']['sell'][0]['Quantity']
Rate_2 = json_data['result']['sell'][0]['Rate']

print ("Buy")
print(Rate)
print(Quantity)
print ("")
print ("Sell")
print(Rate_2)
print(Quantity_2)
```

I want to be able to print what I printed above, for every URL. But I do not know where to begin. This is what I have so far:

```
import grequests
import json


urls = [
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-1ST&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-2GIVE&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-ABY&type=both&depth=50',
]


requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests)
```

I thought it would be something like `print(response.json(['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'] for response in responses))` but that does not work at all, and python returns the following: `print(responses.json(['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'] for response in responses)) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'json'`. I am very new to python, and coding in general, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Instead of saying "but that does not work at all", it would be better to say what the error you get is.  That little phrase risks getting you voted down.

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured it so off base that it would be obvious. Nevertheless, the error I get is `print(responses.json(['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'] for response in responses))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `responses` variable is a list of `Response` objects. If you simple print the list with

```
print(responses)
```

it gives you

```
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
```

the brackets `[]` tell you that this is a list and it contains three `Response`objects.

When you type `responses.json(...)` you are telling python to call the `json()` method on the list object. The list, however does not offer such a method, only the objects *in* the list have it.

What you need to do is access an element in the list and call the `json()` method on this element. This done by specifying the position of the list element you want to access like this:

```
print(responses[0].json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'])
```

This will access the first element in the `responses` list.

Of course, it is not practical to access each list element individually if you want to output many items. That's why there are loops. Using a loop you can simply say: do this for each element in my list. This looks like this:

```
for response in responses:
    print("Buy")
    print(response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'])
    print(response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Rate'])
    print("Sell")
    print(response.json()['result']['sell'][0]['Quantity'])
    print(response.json()['result']['sell'][0]['Rate'])
    print("----")
```

The for-each-loop executes the indented lines of code for each element in the list. The current element is available in the `response` variable.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. It worked perfectly! I appreciate you writing the answer in a way that doesn't just fix my problem, but helps me understand it.

Comment: How do I mark that your answer fixed the problem? I tried upvoting, but my rep is too low.

Comment: Glad I could help. See [here for advise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) on how to accept an answer.